# OpenCV YoloV4-tiny weights and .cfg file?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, yolo, yolov4

Where to find the .cfg file for YoloV4-tiny model.

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases
Here I can see the .cfg for normal YoloV4 and .wights file for both YoloV4 and YoloV4-tiny,
but no .cfg file for YoloV4-tiny.
Also, for normal YoloV4 model I see the new .weights file in latest release (YOLOv4 16 days ago) but no new .cfg file, does it not need a new .cfg file and will work with old .cfg file from YOLOv4 pre-release (May 15, 2020)

(I am trying to run python script on Rpi 4)

Thanks

Comment: Old cfg file will work since the architecture didnt change. You can find tiny v4 weights on the alexey darknet main page linked.

Comment: nice, thanks for clarifying the .cfg doubt. But for tiny I was talking about the missing .cfg file not the .weights. thanks again.

Comment: From the main page (the one with the manual etc.) link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/cfg/yolov4-tiny.cfg and the weigts for completeness: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases/download/darknet_yolo_v4_pre/yolov4-tiny.weights

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The files can be found in the AlexeyAB's [Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) github repository:

- [yolov4-tiny.cfg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/cfg/yolov4-tiny.cfg)
- [yolov4-tiny.weights](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases/download/darknet_yolo_v4_pre/yolov4-tiny.weights)